# Почему параллельный map работает на порядки медленнее последовательного?

Tags: распараллеливание, rust

Хотел поэкспериментировать с параллельностью в Rust, в частности - сравнить последовательный `map` из стандартной библиотеки и параллельный `map` из [rayon](https://github.com/nikomatsakis/rayon). Вот код бенчмарка:

```
#![feature(test)]

extern crate test;
extern crate rand;
extern crate rayon;

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use rayon::prelude::*;
    use test::Bencher;

    #[bench]
    fn iter_test(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let vec: Vec<i64> = (0..20000).collect();

        b.iter(|| -> i64 {
            vec.iter().map(|x| x * x).sum()
        });
    }

    #[bench]
    fn par_iter_test(b: &mut Bencher) {
        let vec: Vec<i64> = (0..20000).collect();

        b.iter(|| -> i64 {
            vec.par_iter().map(|x| x * x).sum()
        });
    }
}
```

Результаты:

```
running 2 tests
test tests::iter_test     ... bench:       8,061 ns/iter (+/- 2,606)
test tests::par_iter_test ... bench:   1,915,544 ns/iter (+/- 40,786,648)
```

Почему параллельный `map` настолько медленный? Я конечно понимаю, что на распараллеливание какие-то ресурсы тратятся, но не столько же. Может последовательный `map` как-то компилятор оптимизирует? Как тогда написать бенчмарк, на примере которого можно будет почувствовать преимущество параллельного `map`?

P. S. Пробовал под передавать в `map` рекурсивный факториал - результаты отличаются не так сильно, но последовательный `map` все равно быстрее.

Comment: с чего ты взял, что он работает медленнее? _Хотел поэкспериментировать с параллельностью в Rust._ - что мешает?

Comment: @Grundy извиняюсь, случайно Enter нажал, не дописав вопрос; смотрите новую версию вопроса

Comment: Я не то чтобы спец, но попробую предположить, что накладные расходы на распараллеливание превышают время выполнения вашей простейшей задачи, а ускорение получится, если считать что-либо намного более сложное чем умножение

Comment: Проверте на выпускной сборке, может rayon зависит от оптимизатора, хотя...  И еще количество элементов попробуйте увеличить. В общем нужно как-то узнать действительно ли он паралеллит циклы.

Comment: @Cerbo видимо `cargo bench` по умолчанию собирает release сборку. Увеличение числа элементов тоже не помогло. Немного быстрее параллельная версия работает если тестить так: `cargo bench -j 16` (по умолчанию `-j 8`, т. к. ядер 8), но все равно катастрофически медленнее последовательной.

Comment: В последнем предложении вы ведь имели в виду последовательный?

Comment: @NickVolynkin да, последовательный. Жаль нельзя уже отредактировать комментарий.

Comment: @ДаниилКолесниченко магия! Но я вообще-то имел в виду последнее предложение вопроса. )

Comment: B `rayon` такой интересный метод есть https://docs.rs/rayon/0.5.0/rayon/par_iter/trait.ParallelIterator.html#method.weight . Попробуйте разные значения задавать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что накладные расходы на распараллеливание на порядки превышают полезную нагрузку в данном случае.

На моей машине (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz) параллельная версия начинает обгонять на 16 000 000 значений, а на 32 000 000 обгон достигает ~25% и дальше уже сильно не растёт

```
mkpankov@mkpankov-OptiPlex-9020 /tmp/rtest [master *]
± % ➜  cargo bench # 16000000
   Compiling rtest v0.1.0 (file:///tmp/rtest)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.70 secs
     Running target/release/deps/rtest-14d3cc84caf097ae

running 2 tests
test tests::iter_test     ... bench:   8,749,482 ns/iter (+/- 465,264)
test tests::par_iter_test ... bench:   7,700,212 ns/iter (+/- 2,354,146)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured


mkpankov@mkpankov-OptiPlex-9020 /tmp/rtest [master *]
± % ➜  cargo bench # 32000000
   Compiling rtest v0.1.0 (file:///tmp/rtest)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.70 secs
     Running target/release/deps/rtest-14d3cc84caf097ae

running 2 tests
test tests::iter_test     ... bench:  17,497,810 ns/iter (+/- 765,301)
test tests::par_iter_test ... bench:  13,826,826 ns/iter (+/- 1,615,362)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured


mkpankov@mkpankov-OptiPlex-9020 /tmp/rtest [master *]
± % ➜  cargo bench # 64000000
   Compiling rtest v0.1.0 (file:///tmp/rtest)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.71 secs
     Running target/release/deps/rtest-14d3cc84caf097ae

running 2 tests
test tests::iter_test     ... bench:  34,855,214 ns/iter (+/- 1,047,213)
test tests::par_iter_test ... bench:  27,347,082 ns/iter (+/- 236,451)

test result: ok. 0 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 2 measured
```